# Is it possible to distinguish between an insight of type Pivot Table and an insight of type Table from the visualizationClass?

Tags: gooddata

I'm working with the GoodData.UI SDK on version 6.3.2.  I've got some code that looks up the type of an Insight given its `visualizationClass` object.  When this code (or a separate lookup) gets the `visualizationClass` of an insight I've created with pivoting features, I get the following:

```
   "visualizationClass" : {
      "content" : {
         "checksum" : "local",
         "icon" : "local:table",
         "iconSelected" : "local:table.selected",
         "orderIndex" : 0.0,
         "url" : "local:table"
      },
      "meta" : {
         ...
         "identifier" : "gdc.visualization.table",
         "isProduction" : 1,
         "summary" : "",
         "tags" : "",
         "title" : "Table",
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

I'd expected there to be some indication here that this was a Pivot Table insight, rather than the older standard Table insight.  I understand that going forward all tables will be pivot tables, but the documentation seems to indicate that both types of tables currently exist.  Is there a way to distinguish these insight types from the `visualizationClass` that I'm missing, or is that not possible?

https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/table_component.html
https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/pivot_table_component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**
It is not possible to distinguish between old Table and new PivotTable, because the `visualizationClass` is identical.

**Long answer**
The PivotTable was designed fully compatible with the older Table. The older Table is a subset of PivotTable functionalities. Thus, every Table is a PivotTable as well, and it is planned to drop the old Table support completely soon.

You should assume that every table created with `visualizationClass.content.url = 'local:table'` is the new PivotTable.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know of documentation that mentions that the visualizationClass hasn't changed?

Comment: Not quite, but we did let our users know about the temporary platform setting `enablePivot` here: https://help.gooddata.com/doc/en/reporting-and-dashboards/analytical-designer/visualize-your-data/insight-types/tables.